# Cheapest gigabit managed switch with telnet capability

Tags: networking, switch

I'm looking for a cheap gigabit managed switch that can be controlled with telnet so I can do some scripting.
The number of ports is of little consequence to me and I was wondering if anyone had any good recommendations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find Dell PowerConnect switches to be of excellent quality/performance and the "mid-range" 3500 series line are very cost effective and include telnet configurability.

Comment: Don't forget to check out the Dell Outlet too http://www.dell.com/outlet (international versions available too)

Answer (score 2):

If web scripting doesn't scare you, then the HP Procurve 1800 series are pretty damn cheap. 200GBP for 24 ports and 90GBP for 8 ports. Sadly, proper telnet/ssh managed switches from HP are quite a bit more expensive.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably best off getting something used off of craigslist.  I have a cisco/linksys [srw2008](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833124087) which does vlan tagging, port mirroring, 802.1x, and so on.  It has a somewhat limited CLI but it does support ssh/telnet.

The linksys is roughly $200.

Answer (score 0):

I also like the Dell Poweredge for the money. They are quite cheap on ebay. If your budget is a bit bigger HP Procurve is great too.